# How to edit google spreadsheets using java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-sheets

Is there a way to edit the google spreadsheets using the java programming in eclipse.
I have a test report coming out from the TestNG Framework and the results should be updated in the google spreadsheet.
Do we have inbuilt libraries, modules etc to import them and do the necessary actions to update the cells in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Did you happen to see this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

Comment: yeah. i looked into that.. is that the only way i can edit the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this (properly) is by hooking on to what APi's google provide.

> https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

like stated above.

the not so proper way would be to get a hold on a webdriver and manually firing commands. but i would not advice this, especially when there are standard API's available.